# Вопросительные номинативные предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Существует ли такое понятие, как "вопросительные номинативные предложения"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вот материал по этой теме:**

Основное значение бытийности (наличия, существования) предметов и явлений у номинативных предложений **может быть осложнено значением указания, эмоциональной оценки, волеизъявления и др.** Ср.: Озеро и Вот озеро; Ночь и Какая ночь! **На этом основано разграничение разновидностей номинативных предложений.** Чаще всего выделяются собственно-бытийные, предметно-бытийные, бытийно-указательные, бытийно-оценочные, бытийно-побу­ди­тель­ные, бытийно-желательные, **бытийно-вопросительные** и собственно-назывные предложения:

7. Функционируют в языке также бытийно-вопросительные предложения: ***Не огонь ли?; Может быть, паром?***

https://lektsii.net/3-141647.html